# database validation in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In MVVM we implement simple validations in the model class by implementing IDataErrorInfo my question is how can we validate business rules in MVVM like user already exist, etc.. currently I am thinking to implement business rules on save command, but the problem is how can I show an error to the user in validation error template the way IDateErrorInfo show error

Comment: updating a question its WPF Mvvm

Answer (score 4):

If you use WPF 4.5 you should take advantage of `INotifyDataErrorInfo`

You want an async validation here because you would need to reach out to the database.

here are some nice articles with background information:

WPF 4.5 – ASYNCHRONOUS VALIDATION https://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/wpf-4-5-validation-asynchrone/

WPF 4.5 – Part 1 : Asynchronous data validation
http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/18/wpf-4-5-asynchronous-data-validation/

HTH

Comment: Gotta love link answers. "anthymecaillard.wordpress.com is no longer available. The authors have deleted this site."